# how to use regex.test class in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i am doing client side validation in Zend framework2 and using regex. test class for this purpose but not getting the correct result 
i m using in the following way

```
var regex = new RegExp('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]{1,50}+$/');
console.log(regex.test(id_val));
```

but it always returns false.
does any one knows how to use it?

Comment: The syntax looks fine.   What's the value of id_val?  Add that to the question.

Comment: Creating a RegExp object using `new` does not take delimiters, and two quantifiers after another are also an error. (Your browser’s JS console should have told you about the latter already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove surrounding `/` from the string literal, and trailing `+`. Also escape `\` as commented by @Bergi.

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\\s]{1,50}$');
regex.test('1'); // => true
```

Or, use the regular expression literal:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]{1,50}$/.test('1'); // => true
```

**Use regular expression literal unless you need to generate regular expression runtime.**

Comment: …and escape the backslash. No, just use the literal instead of the constructor.

Comment: still i m confused that how to enclosed regex in quotes as it is coming in the form of string form another page.